# Use of place prepositions

Tags: prepositions

Here is a question for you: if I say "in front of" it refers to persons that look each other or not? Should I say "opposite"?

Comment: *In front of* and *opposite* give relative position but not orientation. Could you give us an example of a sentence you'd like to use this in? Include that in your question, please, using the 'edit' link below the tag.

Comment: I can't think of a word that would include looking at each other.  We have phrases, though, such as "facing each other".  // Note that "in front of" and "facing each other" sort of contradict.  Since they are facing different ways, what is considered front? There would need to be a broader setting stated, such as "We were standing in line with my girlfriend in front of me. She turned around, facing me."

Answer (score 2):

The prepositional expression **in front of** means ‘close to the front of something or someone’. It is the opposite of behind:

A really tall man was sitting in front of me and I couldn’t see the screen properly. or I was sitting behind a really tall man and I couldn’t see the screen properly.

[Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/in-front-of)

You can read the difference between "opposite" and "in front of"

[Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/opposite-or-in-front-of)

You could have found it by searching in any dictionary

The elephant is **in front of** the chair.

[image: Cambridge Dictionary]

[image]